# run make in background

Tags: c, linux, makefile

I wanted to create a C program to create several different executable binaries from the same Makefile with different names.

but as everytime I run "make" of a pretty large program, they have this bunch logs output... and if i made several of this the terminal would be so "dirty"

So the question, is it actually okay to run "make" in background, so i don't have to see those log?
is it a good idea? or does this actually has no relation with putting it to the background or so?

and if yes, how can i do so?

For the program it's more or less like below, where tmp2 is array of the binaries name

```
for (int j = 0; tmp2[j] != NULL; j++)
    {
        printf("-> %s\n", tmp2[j]);
        char command[128] = "";
        sprintf(command, "make -C %s TARGET=%s all", "file/path/", tmp2[j]);
        system(command);
    }
```

and I tried to look up for running linux command in background like adding & at the end of the command, but it still shows the log

```
text.c:442:3: warning: blablabla
gcc -W -Wall -Wextra -c -g -Os -I. test1.c
gcc -W -Wall -Wextra -c -g -Os -I. test2.c
gcc -g -o STEM_ECS2_SERVICE_3 main.o json.o config.o debug.o -lnsl  -lm -ldl -lc -lmysqlclient  -lm
/bin/mv *.o ./object
```

the log is sth like above, its the simplified version, it's just all the stuff from -Wall and the actual command like `gcc` stuff

So is there actually any way to not see the "make" log?

**EDIT**

for the make file

```
include ../../Make.cf
OBJ_DIR         = ./object

CFLAGS      = -g -Os $(INCDIR) $(MYSQLINC) -I./include -export-dynamic
LDFLAGS     = $(SYSNLIB) $(SYSLIB) $(MYSQLLIB) $(THREADLIB) -L$(LIBDIR) \
              -lmysqlclient  -lm 

C_OBJECTS   =   main.o              \
                json.o              \
                ecs_config.o        \
                ecs_debug.o         \

######### define target #########

all:    $(TARGET)

main.o: main.c
    $(CC) -W -Wall -Wextra -c $(CFLAGS) $(DEFINES) main.c

json.o: json.c
    $(CC) -W -Wall -Wextra -c $(CFLAGS) $(DEFINES) json.c

config.o: config.c
    $(CC) -W -Wall -Wextra -c $(CFLAGS) $(DEFINES) config.c

debug.o: debug.c
    $(CC) -W -Wall -Wextra -c $(CFLAGS) $(DEFINES) debug.c

$(TARGET):   $(C_OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(DEFINES) -std=gnu99 -o $(TARGET) $(C_OBJECTS) $(LDFLAGS)
    $(MV) *.o $(OBJ_DIR)

touch:
    $(TOUCH) *.c

clean:
    $(RM) $(OBJ_DIR)/*.o
    rm -f *.o core $(TARGET)

cp:
    cp -f $(TARGET) $(BINDIR)/$(TARGET)
```

so this make file is actually made by someone else from the group, and I cant really show the exact path to stuff, but hope this help

Comment: How do you actually *run* the `make` command? And what should happen if a command fails, if there's an error or a warning?

Comment: Or you could open x number of instances of your favourite programming IDE, let it handle the builds and from there on worry about more important things, such as the functionality of the program itself.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude oh yes, I forgot to add the code line. I edited it. I think as for the error, it would be exactly the same as how when we run "make" from the terminal

Comment: @Lundin thanks, for this program, i'm trying to manage several programs that run base on the same logic but with different configuration file. It is, exactly, not a critical part of my program, but still wanna know if I can run it in a cleaner manner, since this managing program is suppose to run by itself then let us monitor it simply from their logs and stuff

Comment: The `system` function usually runs the command through the shell or command-line environment, which means you could use normal *redirection* for its output. But then you really have to think about how to handle errors during build, how will those be reported if you're hiding them?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude thankyouu, and good point, i tried "make 2> make_log_error.txt > make_log.txt" and it work perfectly. I should mark your reply as answer but not sure if i can from comment. and one more question, i found this while i was diving through the system command, is it actually a bad idea to use system?

Comment: Do you use a `Makefile`? If yes, show the contents of the `Makefile`. In a `Makefile` you could use `@` to suppress the normal output of a command or use `.SILENT` to suppress all normal output for specified targets. Wouldn't it be easier to use a shell script instead of a C program to run your `make` commands? Your `sprintf` format string contains two `%s` but only one argument. Please [edit] your question to add requested information or clarification.

Comment: @Bodo I do use Makefile. I guess because I'm not familiar with shell scripting, that it never comes to mind, i'll have to look up for shell script then. and the %s  one is for path file another is for the binary name. I'll update it right away

Comment: @Bodo I updated it, I hope it helps, because I cant really attached the whole file as is

Comment: You could even use a `Makefile` to run `make` commands in subdirectories. You should get a compiler warning about the missing argument for the `sprintf` format. I suggest to show in your question what `make` commands you want to run. One way to suppress the normal output is to prefix all commands with `@`. You could replace the 4 similar rules for all object files with a single pattern rule. Moving the object files to a different location will break the purpose of `make` to re-build only the sources that have changed. It will re-build all objects every time because you move them.

Comment: The `@` prefix will only suppress the normal output to `stdout`, not the errors and warnings printed to `stderr`. Using compiler option `-Wall` and suppressing the resulting output does not make sense. If you don't want to see the warnings you should not instruct the compiler to display them. But this is a bad idea. You should better fix the warnings.

Comment: I'm sorry, I mis-read your `sprintf` line. You *do*  have two arguments, so forget my comments about this. But it doesn't make much sense to use a string literal `"file/path/"` as an argument for format `%s`. You could write `sprintf(command, "make -C file/path/ TARGET=%s all", tmp2[j]);` instead.

Comment: Are you perhaps simply looking for `make -s`? Otherwise, as outlined in previous comments, the usual way to run `make` in the background would be to redirect its output to a file so that you can examine what it did later on if you need to.

Comment: @Bodo thankyou very much, so I decided to look a bit more into shell scripting, and try again from there. For the C program, I think I will go with Someprogrammerdude solution and for sure fix the stuff you point out too. Thanks it helps me a lot

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I was wondering if you could post your comment as answer so I could mark this question done, since your answer do exactly what I need in this question case. As for shell scripting i guess thts for another question if any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, running the same make/makefile in parallel with different instances of make can result in race conditions -- so no, it's not a good idea. (eg. if instance 1 of make was trying to access a dependency that instance 2 was in the process of updating, you could end up with corrupt data)

That being said, you can get around that by just using a single instance of make as so:

```
make -j targ1 targ2 targ3
```

This will build `targ1`, `targ2`, and `targ3`, will build dependencies only once for all targets, and will build everything in the correct order etc.

I'm not clear why you would want to call this from a c file rather than just use the command line, but if there is a reason for this, you would want it to look something like:

```
char command[1024] = "";
char *eo_command =  command + sizeof(command);
char *ptr = command;

ptr += snprintf(command, sizeof(command) "make -C %s", "file/path/");
// add some checks to ptr here...

for (int j = 0; tmp2[j] != NULL; j++) {
        ptr += snprintf(ptr, eo_command-ptr, " %s", tmp2[j]);
        // add some checks to ptr here...
}
system(command);
```

If you don't want to see the output, you can pipe the output to `/dev/null`.   Also, if you want it to build faster, you can pass a `-j` flag to the make command line which will allow it to build multiple targets in parallel.

Comment: Would the makefile be containing that targ1 targ2 targ3 then? each would be a copy of $(TARGET):   $(C_OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(DEFINES) -std=gnu99 -o $(TARGET) $(C_OBJECTS) $(LDFLAGS) ... sth like this?

Comment: Your makefile would require something like `POSSIBLE_TARGETS:=targ1 targ2 targ3`,  `$(POSSIBLE_TARGETS) : ` / `$(C_OBJECTS) $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(DEFINES) -std=gnu99 -o $@ $(C_OBJECTS) $(LDFLAGS)` for all possible target names (note the use of the `$@` [automatic variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html)).   If you want it to build whatever the user specifies on the command line (not part of finite set), you could use the [`MAKECMDGOALS`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Goals.html) special variable instead of `POSSIBLE_TARGETS`:

Comment: ohh i think i get the idea, thanks a lot for the suggestion, i'll look more into it

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to close this question since the solution given by @Someprogrammerdude  is the best fitting to my question I think.

So I did fix my problem by changing the code a little bit

```
for (int j = 0; tmp2[j] != NULL; j++)
    {
        printf("-> %s\n", tmp2[j]);
        char command[128] = "";
        sprintf(command, "make -C %s TARGET=%s all 2> make_error_log.txt > make_log.txt", "file/path/", tmp2[j]);
        system(command);
    }
```

Although, since Bodo mentioned it i'm going to learn shell scripting too.
Thanks for all the help

Answer (score -2):

it is possible to call the `make` command with a `&` at the end, so the process spawns in the background, and you get the PID.

Something like that:
`make -SOME_FLAGS &`

Comment: ... which will not work in the intend of the author of the question as the output still goes to the terminal.